# OOP returning variables

Tags: php, oop

Hello I am new to OOP and I have a class with a method and I am trying to return a variable to the class from a method but I am obviously missing something...

Here is my Class:

```
class Certification {

    public $uid;
    public $men_id;
    public $sm_id;
    public $sm_rec;
    public $three_days;
    public $min_on_test;
    public $signed;
    public $mid_year;
    public $police_check;
    public $io_comments;
    public $date_certified;

    public function __construct($uid)
    {   
        include 'conn.php';         
        $stmt = $conn->prepare(
                               'SELECT * FROM certification WHERE uid = :uid');
        $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->uid = $row['uid'];
            $this->nid = $row['nid'];
            $this->nid = $row['date_certified'];
            $this->men_id = $row['men_id'];
            $this->sm_id = $row['sm_id'];
            $this->sm_rec = $row['sm_rec'];
            $this->three_days = $row['three_days'];
            $this->min_on_test = $row['min_on_test'];
            $this->signed = $row['signed'];
            //$this->mid_year = $row['mid_year'];
            $this->police_check = $row['police_check'];
            $this->io_comments = $row['io_comments'];
        }
    }

    public function get_mid_year ($uid) {
        include 'conn.php'; 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare(
                               'SELECT courseReviewed FROM vti_users WHERE uid = :uid');
        $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->mid_year = $row['courseReviewed'];
            return $this->mid_year;     
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that this method would return the `$mid_year` variable to the class but is null when I use `var_dump()`.

Any advice about correcting my flawed logic would be a great help for a beginner.

Comment: How are you calling your method? A few things that are not directly related: 1. You should open 1 database connection and send that to your methods or once to the constructor and set a variable in the class that you can reuse whenever you want. Now every time you instantiate an object or call your method, you will open a new database connection. 2. There should also be no need to send the uid again to your method as it is already set on the object. 3. You could probably get all required information in one go if you use a join in your constructor.

Comment: You don't need to return. `$this` already represents the object instance of the class, so when you do `$this->variable = 'something'`, your variable already has this value.

Comment: You should provide the connection via dependency injection, not as an include.

Comment: Is it possible to get an example  of dependency injection?